# df -h on Unix vs Linux

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I am trying to use Unix NCR and I want to dispay the free disk space etc in the same format as Linux displays them with df -h, however, on Unix I am getting the error "UX:df: ERROR: Illegal option -- h" when I am trying to do df -h. Is this possible? And do you know of any useful resources with regards to Unix vs. Linux commands since I know Linux well but I am still getting used to Unix and I found very limited resources on the internet.

Output as follows:

```
$ df
/proc               (/proc           ):       0 blocks     758 files
/stats              (/stats          ):       0 blocks       0 files
```

Comment: Just look at its `man page` when you encounter a discrepancy like this one.  Since they don't appear to be available online, you'll have to check it on your server.  I don't think the `-h` option (or any equivalent) existed back then, but it provides so little benefit that I wouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: But it doesn't tell you the % free or the size that is free on a partition which I need and don't know how to get to on Unix

Comment: Please show us your `df` output.  It has to show how much is used and free!

Comment: Dont add the picture... add the output in text format

Comment: There's something unusual about your `df` output.  Why would it only refer to `/proc` and `/stats`?

Answer (score 2):

Different variants of Unix have different utilities. There's some common ground (e.g. they all have a `df` utility) but some details differ (e.g. the exact output format and the availability of certain options such as `-h`). Linux ships with [GNU coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) which has more user-friendly options than the same utilities on most other variants, for example the `-h` option.

You can install GNU coreutils on many other Unix variants but I don't know about NCR, it isn't exactly modern or mainstream.

If NCR isn't too ancient, you can at least use all the options standardized by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), which for [`df`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/df.html) includes `-k` to display in kB rather than 512B units and `-P` to display the same columns that GNU/Linux `df` does.

To see what options your version of `df` supports, use [`man df`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

For administration commands, the [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) is useful. I don't know of a similar document for user commands, but the [POSIX/Single Unix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcuix.html) gives an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `df -k` (display size in Kbytes) which should have a similar output on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The `df` argument `-h` is an extension.

From POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/df.html
a UNIX implementation is not required to implement `-h`. In fact this option is not listed.

In fact also LSB doesn't define `-h`, so distribution doesn't "need" to implement it: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/df.html